# TypeError: 'connection' object is not callable in python using mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_restful import reqparse
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL



mysql = MySQL()
app = Flask(__name__)

# MySQL configurations
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'itemlistdb'
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'




    mysql.init_app(app)

    api = Api(app)

    class AuthenticateUser(Resource):
        def post(self):
            try:
                # Parse the arguments

                parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
                parser.add_argument('email', type=str, help='Email address for Authentication')
                parser.add_argument('password', type=str, help='Password for Authentication')
                args = parser.parse_args()

                _userEmail = args['email']
                _userPassword = args['password']

                conn = mysql.connection
                cursor = conn.cursor()
                cursor.callproc('sp_AuthenticateUser',(_userEmail,))
                data = cursor.fetchall()


                if(len(data)>0):
                    if(str(data[0][2])==_userPassword):
                        return {'status':200,'UserId':str(data[0][0])}
                    else:
                        return {'status':100,'message':'Authentication failure'}

            except Exception as e:
                return {'error': str(e)}


    class GetAllItems(Resource):
        def post(self):
            try: 
                # Parse the arguments
                parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
                parser.add_argument('id', type=str)
                args = parser.parse_args()

                _userId = args['id']

                conn = mysql.connection
                cursor = conn.cursor()
                cursor.callproc('sp_GetAllItems',(_userId,))
                data = cursor.fetchall()

                items_list=[];
                for item in data:
                    i = {
                        'Id':item[0],
                        'Item':item[1]
                    }
                    items_list.append(i)

                return {'StatusCode':'200','Items':items_list}

            except Exception as e:
                return {'error': str(e)}

    class AddItem(Resource):
        def post(self):
            try: 
                # Parse the arguments
                parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
                parser.add_argument('id', type=str)
                parser.add_argument('item', type=str)
                args = parser.parse_args()

                _userId = args['id']
                _item = args['item']

                print _userId;

                conn = mysql.connection
                cursor = conn.cursor()
                cursor.callproc('sp_AddItems',(_userId,_item))
                data = cursor.fetchall()

                conn.commit()
                return {'StatusCode':'200','Message': 'Success'}

            except Exception as e:
                return {'error': str(e)}



    class CreateUser(Resource):
        def post(self):
            try:
                # Parse the arguments
                parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
                parser.add_argument('email', type=str, help='Email address to create user')
                parser.add_argument('password', type=str, help='Password to create user')
                args = parser.parse_args()

                _userEmail = args['email']
                _userPassword = args['password']

                conn = mysql.connection
                cursor = conn.cursor()
                cursor.callproc('spCreateUser',(_userEmail,_userPassword))
                data = cursor.fetchall()

                if len(data) is 0:
                    conn.commit()
                    return {'StatusCode':'200','Message': 'User creation success'}
                else:
                    return {'StatusCode':'1000','Message': str(data[0])}

            except Exception as e:
                return {'error': str(e)}



    api.add_resource(CreateUser, '/CreateUser')
    api.add_resource(AuthenticateUser, '/AuthenticateUser')
    api.add_resource(AddItem, '/AddItem')
    api.add_resource(GetAllItems, '/GetAllItems')

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

It throws with an error "connection object is not callable" .
I have searched all possible questions here in @stackoverflow posted before but unable to find the solution for the same.. If anyone has the solution please do help me over it. 
Thank you .

Note: now this code is working... Thank you

Comment: Please be careful to post the *full traceback* including the name of the exception into the question itself.

Comment: i.e. your problem very specifically is that you're catching the exception that you're not prepared to handle, but also you lose the original formatting, and are returning the `str(e)`; minimally you should add `traceback.print_exc()` to your exception handler in such cases while you're still debugging.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala can you please edit the code with yours.. I am very beginer in this.

Comment: Add `import traceback` at the top of your file, and just before `return {'error': str(e)}` add `traceback.print_exc()` so that you can see the actual traceback on the *server side*.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala look the error comes like this ..  File "api.py", line 134
    return {'error': str(e)}
                           ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level   ...I have added  ...  except Exception as e:
   traceback.print_exc()
            return {'error': str(e)}

Comment: yes, and `traceback.print_exc()` needs to be indented at the exact same level as `return`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala then only that error thorws here  return {'error': str(e)} ^ IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121404/discussion-between-tanmoy-sarkar-and-antti-haapala).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace

```
conn = mysql.connect()
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

with

```
conn = mysql.connection
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Read more at the Flask-MySQLdb’s  [docs](http://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: now it thorows an error ...   {
    "error": "global name 'cursor' is not defined"
}

Comment: @TanmoySarkar You have to use `cursor = ` and not `conn = `